# How to get the value from object if having lookup reference ID in apex

Tags: apex, lookup, object, reference

I'm getting the JSON response by using the following code.

```
LiveText__Conversation_Header__c val = LiveTextConversationMap.get(key);

System.debug('Value One'+JSON.serialize(val.valueOne));

System.debug('Value Two:'+JSON.serialize(val.valueTwo));
```

In value one I'm getting the reference id (lookup field) of Case object now I want to access the value of Case object (Suppose case number [CaseNumber]). Please let me know how it can be done.

Comment: That does not look like a valid case id

Comment: That's an example I changed the ID to dummy one

Comment: It is a record ID

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use SOQL to query the record using the id, similar to code below

```
List<case> mycases = [Select CaseNumber,Id from case Where Id = 'Your Id here'];
System.debug(mycases[0].caseNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer that the value can be null, so if you execute this SOQL it will return blank rows.

When you execute that SOQL in Developer console in execute Anonymous mode then SOQL engine automatically includes Id in any query result.

for more details visit: SOQL results returning RecordTypeId which is not included in query